# Почему не работает тест без if __name__ == '__main__'?

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему без строчки `if __name__ == '__main__':` перед `unittest.main()` тест не находит?

Код:

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name


class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Тесты для 'name_function.py'."""

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        """Имена вида 'Janis Joplin' работают правильно?"""
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis Joplin')


unittest.main()
```

В модуле name_function только одна функция:

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    """Строит отформатированное полное имя."""
    full_name = f"{first} {last}"
    return full_name.title()
```

Результат на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую PyCharm последней версии. Знаю, что для того, чтобы тест работал в PyCharm можно вообще эти строчки не добавлять, но хочу разобраться именно с самой логикой: почему без строки `if __name__ == '__main__':` результат как на скриншоте, а если ее добавить, то все работает как надо?

Comment: При запуске через командную строку как `python -m unittest testing.NamesTestCase` модуль testing не запускается, а импортируется, потом уже из него извлекаются тесты и выполняются. Возможно запуск `unittest.main()` при импорте как-то мешает дальнейшему запуску тестов - у меня выкидывает ошибку `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'testing'`. Если `unittest.main()` убрать вообще или спрятать под `if __name__ == "__main__":`, то тест запускается нормально.

Comment: Но ведь я запускаю модуль testing как основную программу. Как он может импортироваться и куда?
Запускаю не через командную строку, а просто нажатием кнопки "Run".

Comment: Еще более странно, что у меня ошибки `AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'testing' ` не выдает, просто тесты не находит (как на скрине).
Может мы с вами по-разному запускаем?

Comment: "Но ведь я запускаю модуль testing как основную программу." - нет, у вас PyCharm запускает тест через `python -m unittest testing.NamesTestCase`, смотрите что в консоли пишет. Ошибку опять же PyCharm может как-то по-своему обрабатывать.

Comment: Похоже вы правы. Если вас не затруднит, объясните пожалуйста почему в этом случае сценарий запуска отличается от стандартного и при запуске testing.py он запускает его через unittest? Очень хочу наконец-то разобраться в этом вопросе.

Также не понимаю почему в этом случае, если он изначально запускает через unittest (и как я понимаю этот модуль в данный момент выступает в качестве основного, а остальные - в роли импортируемых), не запускается нормально `unittest.main()` без дополнительной проверки `if __name__ == '__main__':` ?

Comment: Проверил дополнительно значение глобальной переменной __name__ и действительно у нее значение testing, будто testing импортируемый. Хотя запускаю изначально именно его. Похоже, я окончательно запутался...

Comment: Без понятия, я только могу констатировать факт, глубоко копать мне не интересно.